# Access Cookie created in JS on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I created a cookie via JavaScript, will I be able to access it in PHP too?

**JS to create a cookie**

```
function pb_create_cookie(name, value, days2expire, path) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days2expire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + ';' +
                   'expires=' + expires + ';' +
                   'path=' + path + ';';
}

pb_create_cookie('tour_in_progress', '1', 30, "/");
pb_create_cookie('tour_id', 105, 30, "/");
pb_create_cookie('tour_step', 0, 30, "/");
```

**Cookie usage in PHP**

```
$tour_id       = $_COOKIE['tour_id'];
$tour_progress = $_COOKIE['tour_in_progress'];
$tour_step     = $_COOKIE['tour_step'];
```

Referrence: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript

Comment: Of course the cookies are available in php too. Coding standards? What do you mean?

Comment: Thanks mate. Ignore the coding standards thing, I removed it ..

Comment: What happened to *try and see*? That would have been faster than asking here.

Comment: Well I did, was not working for me but I just found out the problem. Thanks anyways ..